# Multiple versions of handlebars, need to avoid conflict for between them

Tags: jquery, namespaces, handlebars.js, grunt-contrib-uglify

Currently in our project, we have multiple versions of handlebars one is very old 1.1.12 and have written new components with latest version 4.0.*. 
I am able to pre-compile using grunt-contrib-handlebars but facing issues due to conflicts  when i integrated with parent project which is on old version handlebars, i dont have choice to upgrade the version of handlebars from parent project hence looking for a way either using some or other grunt plug in or any option available to namespace my handlebars version.
Any quick help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See [Handlebars.noConflict()](https://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html#base-noConflict). "This allows for distinct versions of the library to be used simultaneously without concern for version conflicts."

Comment: thank you, i will try this and update. i am also thinking about keeping it under local function like (function(handlebars){})(myhandlebars) but am not sure how can this be done while using grunt-contrib-handlebars, i am using this to precompile template and uglify to combine with other js . could you please help.

Comment: Thanks for the support, i am able to achieve it by using Handlebars.noConflict().